# Snowflake and Datadog integration

Tags: docker, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datadog, snowflake-schema

I'm setting up Snowflake and Datadog integration by following [this](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/snowflake/) guide.
I installed datadog agent as a docker container. However, when I try to install the snowflake integration by running the following command inside my datadog-agent docker container (via "docker exec -it --user dd-agent dd-agent bash")

```
datadog-agent integration install datadog-snowflake==2.0.1
```

I got this error

> bash: datadog-agent: command not found

My question is, does datadog-agent docker version support installing integration? If it does, how do I do it? If it doesn't, do I have to install datadog-agent on a VM to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out the datadog-agent inside docker is called `agent`.
So this allows me to call the datadog-agent command

`datadog-agent integration install datadog-snowflake==2.0.1`

However, the latest datadog docker container already include the Snowflake integration plugin. So simply configure the configuration file in
`/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/snowflake.d/conf.yaml`
is enough to get going.